# Arduino - How to control piezo with button?

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

What I am trying to achieve is a button that acts as an on/off switch for playing a tune on a piezo. Initially I want the piezo not to make any sound until the user presses a button, and then they can turn the piezo off by pressing the same button. I'm wondering if anyone can help me figure out what code I need to add to this to get this kind of button functionality.

This is a modified version of the toneMelody sketch that comes with Arduino IDE, I have a button attached to Pin 12, and a Piezo to Pin 8.

```
 #include "pitches.h"

// notes in the melody:
int melody[] ={
NE5,NF5,NG5,ND6,0,NC6,NC6,NB5,NG5,NF5,0,NF5,NF5,NE5,NC5,NF5,NE5,ND5,NC5,NE5,ND5,0,NE5,NF5,NG5,ND6,0,NC6,NC6,NB5,NG5,NF5,0,NF5,NF5,NE5,NC5,NF5,NE5,ND5,NC5,NE5,ND5,0,
0,NC5,NE5,NG5,NG5,NE5,ND5,NE5,ND5,0,NC5,NE5,NG5,NG5,NE5,ND5,0,NE5,0,NC5,NE5,NG5,NG5,NE5,ND5,NE5,ND5,0,NC5,NE5,NG5,NG5,NA5,NE5,0,NE5,
0,NC5,NE5,NG5,NG5,NE5,ND5,NE5,ND5,0,NC5,NE5,NG5,NG5,NE5,ND5,0,NE5,0,NC5,NE5,NG5,NG5,NE5,ND5,NE5,ND5,NF5,0,NE5,0,NC5,NF5,0,NE5,0,NC5,
NE5,NE5,NE5,0,NE5,0,ND5,NE5,NE5,NE5,0,NE5,0,ND5,NE5,NE5,NE5,0,NE5,0,ND5,ND5,NB4,NB4,0,NC5,0,NG5,
NE5,NE5,NE5,0,NE5,0,ND5,NE5,NE5,NE5,0,NE5,0,ND5,NE5,NE5,NE5,0,NE5,0,ND5,ND5,
NE5,NF5,NG5,ND6,0,NC6,NC6,NB5,NG5,NF5,0,NF5,NF5,NE5,NC5,NF5,NE5,ND5,NC5,NE5,ND5,0,NE5,NF5,NG5,ND6,0,NC6,NC6,NB5,NG5,NF5,0,NF5,NF5,NE5,NC5,NF5,NE5,ND5,NC5,NE5,ND5,0,
NE5,NF5,NE5,ND5,ND5,NC5,NC5,NC5,ND5,ND5,NE5,0,NE5,NF5,NE5,ND5,ND5,NC5,NC5,NC5,NG5,ND5,0,
NE5,NF5,NE5,ND5,ND5,NC5
              };
// note durations: 4 = quarter note, 8 = eighth note, etc.:
int noteDurations[] = {
               8,8,8,4,8,4,8,8,8,4,8,4,8,8,8,4,4,8,8,8,2,8,8,8,8,4,8,4,8,8,8,4,8,4,8,8,8,4,4,8,8,8,2,8,
               8,8,8,8,8,16,8,16,8,8,8,8,8,8,16,8,16,8,8,8,8,8,8,16,8,16,8,8,8,8,8,8,16,8,16,8,
               8,8,8,8,8,16,8,16,8,8,8,8,8,8,16,8,16,8,8,8,8,8,8,16,8,16,8,8,16,8,16,8,8,16,8,16,8,
               4,4,8,16,8,16,8,4,4,8,16,8,16,8,4,4,8,16,8,16,8,4,4,8,16,8,16,8,
               4,4,8,16,8,16,8,4,4,8,16,8,16,8,4,4,8,16,8,16,8,2,
               8,8,8,4,8,4,8,8,8,4,8,4,8,8,8,4,4,8,8,8,2,8,8,8,8,4,8,4,8,8,8,4,8,4,8,8,8,4,4,8,8,8,2,8,
               8,8,8,8,4,4,8,8,8,4,2,8,8,8,8,8,4,4,8,8,8,2,8, 
               8,8,8,8,4,1
               };

void setup() {
  // iterate over the notes of the melody:
  for (int thisNote = 0; thisNote < 240; thisNote++) {

    // to calculate the note duration, take one second 
    // divided by the note type.
    //e.g. quarter note = 1000 / 4, eighth note = 1000/8, etc.
    int noteDuration = 1000/noteDurations[thisNote];
    tone(8, melody[thisNote],noteDuration);

    // to distinguish the notes, set a minimum time between them.
    // the note's duration + 30% seems to work well:
    int pauseBetweenNotes = noteDuration * 1.30;
    delay(pauseBetweenNotes);
    // stop the tone playing:
    noTone(8);
  }
}

void loop() {
  // no need to repeat the melody.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I would use a button would be like this. I added comments above and below were I added stuff. The out come of this will be that when you press the button the whole song will play then stop until you press the button again. You can see what kind of button I am taking about here http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Button it also gives you some example code, for you to look at just incase I messed up, if I did mess up 
just message me and I will show you how to fix.

```
#include "pitches.h"

// notes in the melody:

int melody[] ={

NE5,NF5,NG5,ND6,0,NC6,NC6,NB5,NG5,NF5,0,NF5,NF5,NE5,NC5,NF5,NE5,ND5,NC5,NE5,ND5,0,NE5,NF5,

NG5,ND6,0,NC6,NC6,NB5,NG5,NF5,0,NF5,NF5,NE5,NC5,NF5,NE5,ND5,NC5,NE5,ND5,0,

0,NC5,NE5,NG5,NG5,NE5,ND5,NE5,ND5,0,NC5,NE5,NG5,NG5,NE5,ND5,0,NE5,0,NC5,NE5,NG5,NG5,NE5,ND

5,NE5,ND5,0,NC5,NE5,NG5,NG5,NA5,NE5,0,NE5,

0,NC5,NE5,NG5,NG5,NE5,ND5,NE5,ND5,0,NC5,NE5,NG5,NG5,NE5,ND5,0,NE5,0,NC5,NE5,NG5,NG5,NE5,ND


5,NE5,ND5,NF5,0,NE5,0,NC5,NF5,0,NE5,0,NC5,

NE5,NE5,NE5,0,NE5,0,ND5,NE5,NE5,NE5,0,NE5,0,ND5,NE5,NE5,NE5,0,NE5,0,ND5,ND5,NB4,NB4,0,NC5,

0,NG5,

NE5,NE5,NE5,0,NE5,0,ND5,NE5,NE5,NE5,0,NE5,0,ND5,NE5,NE5,NE5,0,NE5,0,ND5,ND5,

NE5,NF5,NG5,ND6,0,NC6,NC6,NB5,NG5,NF5,0,NF5,NF5,NE5,NC5,NF5,NE5,ND5,NC5,NE5,ND5,0,NE5,NF5,

NG5,ND6,0,NC6,NC6,NB5,NG5,NF5,0,NF5,NF5,NE5,NC5,NF5,NE5,ND5,NC5,NE5,ND5,0,

NE5,NF5,NE5,ND5,ND5,NC5,NC5,NC5,ND5,ND5,NE5,0,NE5,NF5,NE5,ND5,ND5,NC5,NC5,NC5,NG5,ND5,0,

NE5,NF5,NE5,ND5,ND5,NC5
              };
// note durations: 4 = quarter note, 8 = eighth note, etc.:

int noteDurations[] = {
               8,8,8,4,8,4,8,8,8,4,8,4,8,8,8,4,4,8,8,8,2,8,8,8,8,4,8,4,8,8,8,4,8,4,8,8,8,4,4,8,8,8,2,8,
               8,8,8,8,8,16,8,16,8,8,8,8,8,8,16,8,16,8,8,8,8,8,8,16,8,16,8,8,8,8,8,8,16,8,16,8,
               8,8,8,8,8,16,8,16,8,8,8,8,8,8,16,8,16,8,8,8,8,8,8,16,8,16,8,8,16,8,16,8,8,16,8,16,8,

               4,4,8,16,8,16,8,4,4,8,16,8,16,8,4,4,8,16,8,16,8,4,4,8,16,8,16,8,

               4,4,8,16,8,16,8,4,4,8,16,8,16,8,4,4,8,16,8,16,8,2,
               8,8,8,4,8,4,8,8,8,4,8,4,8,8,8,4,4,8,8,8,2,8,8,8,8,4,8,4,8,8,8,4,8,4,8,8,8,4,4,8,8,8,2,8,

               8,8,8,8,4,4,8,8,8,4,2,8,8,8,8,8,4,4,8,8,8,2,8, 

               8,8,8,8,4,1

               };


//int to identify what digital pin the button is hooked up to

// can Chang 2 if put button on a different pin

int buttonPin = 2;

void setup() {

//says button pin is a input

    pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);   

// I might say make a int = to the pin you have

// your sound maker on, name it soundMakerPin, and the uncomment the line below

//  pinMode(soundMakerPin, OUTPUT); 

}

void loop(){

// read the button

  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

  // check if the pushbutton is pressed.

  // if it is, the buttonState is HIGH:

  if (buttonState == HIGH) {  

    // play song

song(); 

}

}


//function named song, call this and your song should play

void song(){

// iterate over the notes of the melody:

  for (int thisNote = 0; thisNote < 240; thisNote++) {

    // to calculate the note duration, take one second 

    // divided by the note type.

    //e.g. quarter note = 1000 / 4, eighth note = 1000/8, etc.

    int noteDuration = 1000/noteDurations[thisNote];

    tone(8, melody[thisNote],noteDuration);

    // to distinguish the notes, set a minimum time between them.

    // the note's duration + 30% seems to work well:

    int pauseBetweenNotes = noteDuration * 1.30;

    delay(pauseBetweenNotes);

    // stop the tone playing:

    noTone(8);

  }

}
```

Comment: Didn't pop out the way I wanted, but all the code should be there